# How to check if flashlight is activated?

Tags: cyanogenmod, tasker, camera-flash

I've got a brandnew OnePlus One with Cyanogenmod 12 on it, and the device is rooted.

I like the offscreen gestures very much. But sometimes they are triggered accidentally. This is very costy when the flashlight is turning on and you don't get it.

So my thought was, to write a task with Tasker, which let the phone vibrate, when the flashlight has been enabled.

But unfortunately I have no clue how. I looked for a solution in the web, but I didn't find anything. So maybe you have an idea how I could achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know whether you noticed it but when flashlight is active three files jumps into the scene: `/system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon`, `/system/bin/sensors.qcom`, and  `/system/bin/mediaserver`.

Comment: I created a profile based on Proximity sensor in Tasker (if flashlight is accidentally activated then I'm assuming that the device is in your pocket or bag) and killed `/system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon` whenever proximity sensor detected something. It works, but I can't restart the daemon easily. It takes hell lot of time to restart.. If I kill mediaserver, then all works well except that my device restarted when profile repeated the task execution multiple times. May be you can use the idea to go further.