# How to disable flashlight in lock screen in Lollipop on Xcover 3?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop

Since upgrading my Samsung Galaxy Xcover 3 phone to Android 5.1 Lollipop, I've noticed that the flashlight keeps getting turned on in my pocket. Apparently, pressing the "Xcover button" on the side of the phone will now toggle the flashlight on and off even in the lock screen.

I've tried to find some way to turn this behavior off, but I'm not seeing anything in the settings that would look promising. My attemps to Google for a solution just yield instructions for *enabling* flaslight access from the lock screen on versions *prior to* Lollipop.

Short of getting a more robust case for my phone, how can I keep my pockets from shining in the dark?

Comment: Related: [How to check if flashlight is activated?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/114796)

Comment: @ Firelord: Alas, I don't think installing CyanogenMod and writing a script to control the flashlight is really the most practical solution here. At least, I really hope it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, and found a solution!

Download a random app (one that you don't actually need) from Play Store, then go to Settings (*Personal* / *Xcover key*) and change the button to open that app. Test that it works, and then delete the app, and now the button does nothing. ;)

Comment: Good idea! The only problem is that this also disables the button when the phone is unlocked, which is not ideal, but I guess I can just add the flashlight app to my home screen instead. I did some testing, though, and it seems that if I bind the button to some random game, it will *not* launch from the lock screen -- it seems that the real problem (to me) is that the built-in flashlight app has some permission that lets it bypass the screen lock. So I think if I found a third-party flashlight app with fewer permissions, and bound the button to that, it *should* work the way I want it...

Answer (score 2):

Today my girlfriend's father ask me how to solve it.
I've just written an lightweight app (7kB) which does nothing at all.

Download it from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mklimek.xcoverdisabler) and set as your XCover button app :)

Comment: the app should be available within 2 hours from now...

Comment: That's... awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this will disable the torch: Go to SETTINGS then ACTIVE KEY press SHORT PRESS and select NO ACTION, this should now disable the torch but leave the camera active on a long press.

Comment: I don't see that option on my XCover 3 (Android 5.1.1). Also (possibly related), on my phone the settings item is called "Xcover key", not "Active key".